# Simple RPI3 / Garage Door help?

Tags: relay, wiring

I have a very simple RPI3 / SainSmart 8 channel SSR setup.
I have GPIO18 set as `out` and wired to the relay board.
I can turn on the relay (at least its LED lights appropriately).

My issue is that it will not trigger the garage door opener. I have the relay wired straight through to the COM / PB terminals on the opener.

If I short both these terminals with a screwdriver the door opens as expected...

The opener is a Wayne Dalton Pro-Drive 3222C-Z.

What am I missing?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Steve Robillard (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/56/steve-robillard) for the answer:

SSRs are typically for AC; not DC.

Comment: Actually, SSRs are typically for DC, you just bought the wrong ones.